# Program an Arduino with another Arduino

Tags: programmer

[image]

Is there any way I can program an Arduino using another Arduino,without the need of any computer. I want to store the programming code in the EEPROM of the "Programmer Arduino" and using any interface like SPI, I2C or Serial, **burn** this code to the Second arduino. Is it possible? How can it be implemented ?

Comment: Just use the ISP interface, which is similar to SPI.

Comment: will it work without a computer?

Comment: Depends on your programming skills...

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you really trying to do?

Comment: The code which is compiled by the arduino IDE is stored inside the arduino and this code will be burnt to any atmega328p chip which is connected to this arduino using any interface

Comment: This will give me the ability to program this chip with a compact circuit rather than connecting it to the laptop and burning it

Comment: Stack Exchange isn't google. Please google your ideas and try them out before asking on SE. It's VERY likely someone else has had the same idea/problem and made a tutorial or video on it.

Comment: You could store just a small program into an EEPROM. For example ATmega328 has 32 KB of program memory and just 1 KB of EEPROM. Besides that, instruction opcodes are 16 bit  so you could store only 512 instructions in 1 KB of EEPROM space. But yes, you could store the opcodes as data in flash and write a program (or use a bootloader for that purpose) to send the firmware over serial communication to another Arduino board.

Comment: Th 328 doesn't have enough memory for this. Memory allowing, it is a simple task. Take a look at the 'Arduino As ISP' examples and code.

Comment: Storing the program on an SD card and using an Arduino to read that data and program it into another Arduino is perfectly possible. Either through ISP or through serial using the STK500 protocol for the bootloader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly possible to do this.

> I want to store the programming code in the EEPROM of the "Programmer Arduino" and using any interface like SPI, I2C or Serial, burn this code to the Second arduino.

I should point out that the EEPROM may not be large enough for this. For example, the Uno has only 1KB of EEPROM.

A more workable solution would be to store a reasonable size program in PROGMEM, or a larger one in external memory, like an SD card.

I have a [page about a stand-alone programmer](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11638) - the first idea presented just uses the Serial monitor to command the programmer behaviour:

[image: Board programmer]

Using the Serial Monitor you select the file you want programmed. Another approach, commissioned by someone who wanted to eliminate the external computer altogether looks like this:

[image: Stand-alone programmer]

In this case you put one or more hex files onto the SD card, choose one using the "file select" knob, and then press the "program" button to program it. This only takes a couple of seconds.

There are also commercial products that do a similar thing.

Comment: Worth bearing in mind that something like an ESP-01 has much larger memory than the Uno's 1k - 512kB or 1MB - and is smaller and cheaper. Other models have more memory /flash still.

Comment: True, but the question was about 2 x Atmega328P.

Comment: Hence why I said it was also worth considering. Perhaps he's not 100% unchangably committed to that particular device for the programmer - an XY problem perhaps.

Comment: Quite possibly. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Connect 2 arduinos via serial connection (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial), restart one of them via RESET channel and upload sketch(https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoProMini#toc1). You will need binary files - google 'arduino get sketch binary'(cannot add any more links).

Comment: add as may as you want